# How to modify configuration lines using shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a `phppgadmin` configuration file (`/usr/share/phppgadmin/conf/config.inc.php`)
It has a line:

```
$conf['extra_login_security'] = false;
```

I would like to change it to:

```
$conf['extra_login_security'] = true;
```

using `bash` shell-script. I understand that I would have to use something like sed/awk. But don't know how exactly to use it to do what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a simple global substitution of false to true then `sed 's/false/true/g'` will do it.

```
$ echo "conf['extra_login_security'] = false" | sed 's/false/true/g'
conf['extra_login_security'] = true
```

However to only change lines the start with `conf[` and just change the value to true then this is better `sed 's/\(^.*conf\[.*\] =\) false/\1 true/g'`

```
echo "conf['extra_login_security'] = false" | sed 's/\(^.*conf\[.*\] =\) false/\1 true/g'
conf['extra_login_security'] = true
```

**EDIT:**

Just that line can be done with the following:

`sed -i 's/\(^.*conf\[.extra_login_security.\] =\) false/\1 true/' /usr/share/phppgadmin/conf/config.inc.php`

Use `-i` to save the changes to the file, or redirect to a new file if you don't want to overwrite the original.

`sed 's/\(^.*conf\[.extra_login_security.\] =\) false/\1 true/' > mynewfile.php`

A trick if you don't have permission to write `mynewfile.php` is to pipe the output to `tee` and `sudo` that:

`sed 's/\(^.*conf\[.extra_login_security.\] =\) false/\1 true/' | sudo tee mynewfile.php`

From `man tee` tee - read from standard input and write to standard output and files.